# MongoDB Atlas weirdly wrapping Chinese keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to use the MongoDB atlas with some of the keys being in Chinese characters. However, it is wrapping the Chinese word one/two characters at a time. This makes things hard to read. Is there a way to improve the readability of the table?

[image: MongoDB format]

Comment: I don't think that isproblem of MonogDB Atlas, it's a behavior of your client application. Unfortunately you don't tell us which client you are using.

Comment: "However, _it_ is wrapping..."  What is _"it"_ doing the wrapping?

Comment: If this is what you are seeing in the Atlas UI (eg in Data Explorer), then you might want to reach out to the vendor about it. Doubtful there is anything you or we can do about it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I use cloud.mongodb.com.

Comment: @user20042973 sure, I might try using different client